# How to make administrator's notification about products for ecommerce in user's cart

Tags: python, django

I dicided to make a simle ecommerce shop in django/python.  I have made the shop cart, where user put products. But I don't know how to do administrator's notification  about products user dicided to buy. I want only notification without pay process.
Thanks, for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mmmmm, I'm not sure this is a good idea. Just think about 300 users buying 10 items each one. It's insine!!! On the other hand all the products in the cart don't necessarily will be purshased the user might put it back out of the cart.

On the other hand if what you want is trace the times a product is purshased just add that field to the `Product` model and increase it each time that product is bought.

A completly reasonable idea is notify each time someone buy a product by first time or that a product have been purshased 100 times, etc...

Said this, you can send an email to the administrator about that. The place for the code that sends that email could be inside the view "purshase" (or "buy" or "pay", etc...).

See [Django Sending email](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/email/) documentation.

Comment: If the answer present some utility for you, please remember upvote it.